# View Order of Framelayout

Tags: android, view, android-framelayout, bringtofront, android-unity-plugin

Here is the sample code:

```
FrameLayout Root = new FrameLayout(this);
this.addContentView(Root, LayoutParam0);
setContentView(this);

GLSurfaceView gls = new GLSurfaceView(this);
Root.addView(gls,0, LayoutParam1);

View view = new UnityPlayer(this);
Root.addView(view,1, LayoutParam2);
```

I want to let `view` on top and `gls` on the bottom, but some android device will let `gls` on top. How can I fix it?

p.s. `bringToFront()` some android device will let it go to bottom.

Comment: it is recommneded that FrameLayout should be used only having one direct child

Comment: post the output of  `adb shell dumpsys activity top` command (only the UI subtree starting from your `FrameLayout`)

Comment: to @pskink [link](https://www.codepile.net/pile/kledgwW3)

Comment: you have two child views: `GLSurfaceView` and `UnityPlayer`, but your code shows that you are adding `GLSurfaceView` and `View`

Comment: that just sample. `view = new UntyPlayer(this)`

Comment: `view` has index == 1, the docs say: `"Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top."` so `view` is on top

Comment: Unfortunately `view` is on the bottom for this android device.